# libGDX, transparent sprite is black on some devices

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite

I have recently started learning libGDX and currently, I'm making an endless space game. I have made a scrolling background, where there is a base image of space overlapped with another image with stars.
[Looks like this. (the black area is transparent)](http://picload.org/image/irlirrc/4.png)

Stars move a bit faster, what creates nice effect, as if they were closer. It works fine on my mobile phone and tablet, however if I try it on another tablet with slightly different resolution, the whole stars image becomes black and covers the whole space image.

Everything is saved in PNG and I move the sprite by changing it's Y.

```
stars = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/universe/stars1.png")));
stars.setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
stars.setY(0);
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What is the image size ?

Comment: 1600x900 and I always scale it to fit screen exactly

Comment: Is your second tablet old ? Some old or low cost devices are sometimes unable to load textures when the size is too big for their gpu to handle.
Read : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/77818/why-isnt-my-background-drawing-to-the-screen/77828#77828

Comment: Yes, it's an older one. I cannot try it yet, but that should be it since I couldn't find any other problem. Really appreciate your help.